# How to get product collection with custom attribute option and out of stock is 0?

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

Trying to find product collection with custom attribute option 'Show Room' as filter and out of stock that is 'is_in_stock' attribute is equal to 0

```
 $sAttributeName = 'sale_by';
    $mOptionValue = 'Show Room';
    $_get_show_room_sale_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_get_show_room_sale_products
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 0)
    ->addFieldToFilter(
    $sAttributeName,
    array(
        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getAttribute($sAttributeName)
                    ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionId($mOptionValue)
    )
    );
```

But I am getting following error

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in..../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816**

What am i miss here.Please advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For attribute filter -

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name','your-attribute');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('your-attribute', array('eq' => 'attr-value'));
```

For out of stock filter

```
$collection->joinField(
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                )
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0));
```

Comment: I have try with same but it return me all product